# Is It Okay To Use Real Designs In My 2D Game? [Cars and Weapons]

Tags: legal, copyright, car

I am making a 2D mobile game that includes cars and weapons (like GTA let's say). I am using real car and weapons designs to make 2D images, however, I use made-up names for the both cars and the weapons. Is it still copyrighted?

For example; Traffic Racer and Traffic Rider. In the games, the car models are exactly the same as the real ones, but there is no logo nor name in Traffic Racer. In Traffic Rider, you can clearly see BMW in the game (both the design and the logo). Because of these examples, I think, my situation should be okay since the game is not even 3D.

Comment: This has been asked multiple times before, if you do a search for "real car" on this site you'll find the other questions and the answer you are looking for will be there.

Comment: [Similarly for weapons](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/112145/39518)

Comment: My question is a bit different than the other one. For example; is this image copyrighted?

https://img.itch.zone/aW1hZ2UvMTI4OTQ5LzY5MDU1MC5naWY=/original/gdVxp0.gif

Comment: Copyright is automatic in many jurisdictions. As soon as someone creates a work, they hold copyright over it, without any required registration/etc. But what you're likely to run into here are trademarks and trade dress, which form a different area of intellectual property law. This is what prevents someone from selling a car that looks *almost* like a BMW and calling it a BMVV instead. ;)